# How can i get the original id of an id to color algorithm?

Tags: java, rgb, bitwise-operators

I have the following function to convert a given id of an object into an RGB color:

```
int r = ((int) id & 0x000000FF) >> 0;
int g = ((int) id & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
int b = ((int) id & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
```

How would I receive the original id if I can get the RGB color from the mouse pixel?
I can't wrap my mind around these bit operations.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
my approach:

```
int r = pixels[index] & 0xFF;
int g = pixels[index + 1] & 0xFF;
int b = pixels[index + 2] & 0xFF;

return r + g * 256 + b * 256 * 256;
```

**EDIT 2**
example: Input: 50 -> RGB : 255,0,0 returned value: -1,0,0 -> ID: 255

Comment: id = r+g*256+b*256*256?

Comment: i thought so too but somehow it doesnt work....

Comment: `r + (g << 8) + (b << 16)`? Don't see why that would be different, but it's phrasing it in similar terms to the forwards operation. Please can you show the value of `id` (as hex); the values of `r`, `g` and `b` (as hex); and the value of `r + g * 256` etc (as hex).

Comment: (Ofc, you're discarding the 8 most significant bits, so you can only hope to recover the original value if `id & 0xFF000000 == 0`. The fact you're having to cast to `int` suggests that `id` is a `long`, `float` or `double` (because you wouldn't need the cast otherwise), in which case those 8 MSBs of an int are unlike to be zero)

Comment: @AndyTurner i see so what should i do then? (the input is btw float)

Comment: You need another variable (traditionally, `a`) to hold the 8 MSBs.

Comment: What's the range of those float values? And why are you using float in the first place? If the float values actually are integers only the type would just be wrong, if they also have fractions then the cast to `int` already loses information and you won't be able to reconstruct that.

Comment: Ok so i just change the float to an int??

Comment: One way to address Thomas' comment would be to use `Float.floatToIntBits` instead of casting (which can be losslessly converted back to a float using `Float.intBitsToFloat`) (and have another variable for the MSBs)

Comment: Wdym with the other variable can you show me an implementation? I am really bad with bit operators. Appreciate it!

Comment: `int a = ((int) id & 0xFF000000) >> 24;`

Comment: ok and how would i include that in the method for the returned id? Would it be r + g * 256 + b * 256 * 256 + a * 256 * 256 * 256???